# Can I use a 16bit memory with an 8 bit processor?

Tags: ram, eeprom, rom

> The address bus is typically a double octet wide (i.e. 16-bit), due to practical and economical considerations. This implies a direct address space of only 64 kB on most 8-bit processors

This quote is from Wikipedia of 8 bit computing. It shows us that we can use a 16 bit memory with an 8 bit processor, and this sounds promising to the question of how to access more than 15 addresses from our ROM, but will this affect the usage of our processor itself? The only thing I need to keep 16 bit will be the address register, isn't it?im not using a processor but im interested in building one , this link - [How can 8-bit processor support more than 256 bytes of RAM?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57950/how-can-8-bit-processor-support-more-than-256-bytes-of-ram) , doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more details in order to have an answerable question.  If you are using an existing processor, *identify it specifically*.  If you are *designing* a processor (hopefully in an FPGA!) then you probably want to study some 8-bit designs with 16 bit address space first.  All of your address calculation logic will need to be able to generate a 16 bit output, and you'll need a way to do at least a register-relative if not an absolute load/store and branch...

Comment: I think this post will help answer your question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57950/how-can-8-bit-processor-support-more-than-256-bytes-of-ram

Comment: You CAN use a 16 bit memory on an 8 bit CPU ... trivially, by ignoring half the data bus and half the memory, at least. But that's not even vaguely related to what this quotation is saying. Quotation is about address bus width which is completely irrelevant to data width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can 8-bit processor support more than 256 bytes of RAM?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57950/how-can-8-bit-processor-support-more-than-256-bytes-of-ram)

Comment: Please clarify if you mean using a memory with 16-bit data or 16-bit address bus. Because both are possible as long as the memory is still byte-addressable. Or if you are willing to waste half of it. The memory size is not a problem, in theory you can connect as much memory as you want to a 8-bit processor, be it 1 megabyte or 4 gigabytes.

Comment: 16-bit memory is the width of the data, not the width of the address bus

Comment: @jsotola But the Wikipedia quote describes 16-bit addressing of 8-bit memory. Hence the need to clarify which the OP means.

Comment: If you have tried making a processor, you should have realized that the processor has lots of parts inside it and nothing forces them to all be the same size. This part can be 16 bits even if that part is 8 bits. Of course, that means if you want to transfer data from that part to this part, you can only transfer half at a time.